# Unable to bind ListView Button Click in a UserControl to a Command in ViewModel (MVVM Light Windows 10)

Tags: listview, binding, windows-10, uwp, mvvm-light

I have a `ListView` where the `ItemTemplate` `DataTemplate` is placed in a separate user control.

```xml
<local:ViewBase
x:Class="FindTheCat.Views.ShopPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FindTheCat.Views"
xmlns:control="using:FindTheCat.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
DataContext="{Binding Path=ShopPage, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

<Grid x:Name="gridRoot">
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin800">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
....

    <RelativePanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockTitle" Text="Shop" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="24,48,24,28" FontSize="64"/>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RelativePanel.Below="textBlockTitle" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="0,28,0,0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" IsItemClickEnabled="False">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <control:ShopItemTemplate />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
</local:ViewBase>
```

`ShopItemTemplate` is a user control.

```xml
<UserControl
x:Class="FindTheCat.UserControls.ShopItemTemplate"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FindTheCat.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
mc:Ignorable="d"
>

<Grid x:Name="grid" Width="600" Margin="0,36" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border >
        <Image x:Name="image" Height="160" Width="160" Source="{Binding Uri}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Border>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Grid.Column="1" Margin="16,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="24"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnBuy" Content="{Binding Price, ConverterParameter=Buy, Converter={StaticResource PrependStringConverter}}" FontSize="24" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="txtTitle" RelativePanel.Below="txtDescription" Style="{StaticResource ButtonBuyStyle}" Background="#74b025" Width="256" Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=gridRoot, Path=DataContext.BuyItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin800">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

...

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The binding works fine visually as every element is showing correctly but the `Click` event of `btnBuy` in `ShopItemTemplate`  does not call the `BuyItemCommand` in the `ShopPageViewModel`

```cs
    public ShopPageViewModel()
    {
        BuyItemCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(id => buyItem(id));

        if (!IsInDesignMode)
        {
            loadMockData();
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand<string> BuyItemCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void buyItem(string id)
    {
        Sound.Play(Sounds.Click);
        InAppPurchase.BuyItem(id);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I only need to specify the correct datacontext using my  `ViewModelLocator` as `StaticResource` . So in my case the lines

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=gridRoot, Path=DataContext.BuyItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

become

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
        <Core:InvokeCommandAction 
                        Command="{Binding Path=ShopPage.BuyItemCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"   
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
 </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

`ShopPage` is my View and its ViewModel is accessible using `ShopPage.BuyItemCommand`